# Annoying box in NetBeans IDE

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, ide

When I scrolling down window with code, on top of window a some kind of box appearing, with code preview on actual cursor position. Is there any option to turn it off?
(I can't make screen of this, because it's disappearing at any key press.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the preview of the actual cursor location but it will show the top of the code block. This will helpful when you have a long code block like long `if` conditions or switch cases or even a method because it will show the top or the beginning of a condition, method or a loop.

But if you want to hide them go to

Tools-->Options
Then select editor tab
click on General sub tab and under 'Braces Matching' uncheck show tooltips and click Apply and Ok.

[image]